# pesapal payment gateway in cs cart

Tags: php, paypal, cs-cart

I'm new to cscart payment gateway. I need to implement pesapal payment gateway in my site .

I have the following code in pesapal.php

```
$pesapal_data['oauth_consumer_key']=$consumer_key;
  $pesapal_data['oauth_nonce']='+7BADF195E1-54E0-F881-CC6B-83AF5C68F368+7';
  $pesapal_data['oauth_timestamp']='1421737062';
  $pesapal_data['oauth_version']='1.0';
  $pesapal_data['oauth_callback']=$callback_url;
  $pesapal_data['pesapal_request_data']=$post_xml;
  $pesapal_data['oauth_signature_method']='HMAC-SHA1';
  fn_create_payment_form('http://demo.pesapal.com/api/PostPesapalDirectOrderV4', $pesapal_data, 'Pesapal');
```

But i got  below error

http://demo.pesapal.com/api/home/notfound/ . How to do ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
use Tygh\Registry;

if (!defined('AREA')) {die('Access denied'\);}


if (defined('PAYMENT_NOTIFICATION')) {
         //get order id
        $order_id = $_GET['order_id'];

        //get pyment info...
        $payment_id = db_get_field("SELECT payment_id FROM ?:orders WHERE order_id = ?i", $order_id);


        $processor_data = fn_get_payment_method_data($payment_id);  


        $confirm = ===> pay is ok


        if (failed) {
            //failed
            fn_change_order_status($order_id, 'F', '', false);
            fn_finish_payment($order_id, $_POST, false);
            fn_order_placement_routines('route', $order_id, false);

            echo implode(", ", $webservice->errors);
        } else {




            //success
            fn_change_order_status($order_id, 'P', '', false);
            fn_finish_payment($order_id, $_POST, false);
            fn_order_placement_routines('route', $order_id, false);
        }

} else {

    $terminalId = $processor_data['processor_params']['merchant_id'];
    $userName = $processor_data['processor_params']['user_name'];
    $password = $processor_data['processor_params']['password'];

    $current_location = Registry::get('config.http_location');
    $url = $current_location . "/$index_script?dispatch=payment_notification.notify&payment=paynem&order_id=$order_id&pid=";



    $webservice = new BankMellat($terminalId, $userName, $password);

    $action = $webservice->PayAction($order_info['total'], $url, true);

    if ($webservice->errors) {
        echo implode(", ", $webservice->errors);
    } else {
        echo ('<html><head></head><body>
```

.
.
.
.
 ');}

```
}
```

// this code worked for me